# Pedagogy of Teaching the Inverse Matrix Method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education

I am teaching a group of (ordinary rather than honours) second-year engineers and we are studying matrices. I told the class today that as far as I could see we were only studying matrices and, particularly, the inverse matrix method as an introduction to more advanced matrix methods that would be studied in future.

However, the maths modules that they take in their next, final, third year are differential equations (no linear systems of differential equations) and, well, probability and statistics.

The only use that I can see that this group have for matrices is for solving linear systems. I know that there are plenty of more reasons to study matrices and in particular matrix inverses but this cohort will not see them.

It obviously strikes me as odd that the syllabus would recommend that we use the Inverse Matrix Method rather than the full Gaussian elimination theory.

Therefore my question is:

> Assuming that we want to solve a linear system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, what advantages, if any, does the inverse matrix method have over the full Gaussian elimination theory.

Thank you in advance for any answers; I am struggling to find one!

Comment: A great advantage of the inverse matrix method is that, when you have to solve $Ax=b$ and then $Ax=b'$, you do the job only once.

Comment: The inverse matrix method of solution mimics what they know from the scalar case: to solve $ax=b$, multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$. (This potentially works both ways: it can help with understanding the inverse matrix method, and can help with understanding division as multiplication by a multiplicative inverse.)

Comment: Yeah, basically with the inverse matrix method, you end up with both the solution and the inverse matrix !

Comment: @user12477 yes I did appreciate this point at the time... when I asked them how to solve the matrix equation $AX=B$ from what they knew about the equation $ax=b$ someone said "bring over..." or words to that effect. I was able to talk to them about algebra at this point.

Comment: @julien If I could come up with system/network such that the coefficients are a function of the system and the vector of constants something that can change from problem to problem this would be a nice point to make.

Comment: @DamienL Ah yes but what are they going to the with the inverse matrix once they have the solution. In a properly designed programme where they use the inverse in later modules this would be useful alright.

Comment: The real problem for me is that the inverse matrix method is of no use. At a theoretical level, you just need to know the matrix is invertible. At a concrete level, computers will do it easy.
So I see no good motivation to learn this.

Comment: @DamienL This is my concern; of course at a theoretical level it doesn't even solve all of your linear systems.

Comment: The whole art of numerical linear algebra is to solve your problem without inverting a matrix, or multiplying two matrices together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I teach linear algebra (it has been some years now), I always tell my students to *never ever* compute the inverse of a matrix, at least not if the matrix is much bigger than $3\times3$. If you need to solve $Ax=b$ for just one single $b$, do Gaussian elimination. If you need to do it for several $b$ values but a single $A$, compute the $LU$ decomposition of $A$ and use that to compute the required solutions.

Comment: Thank you Harold. It looks like I will move to change the module content. This kind of thing is daft; it doesn't help the students nor the one teaching the material.